# TCP client does not detect server disconnection

Tags: .net, sockets, winsock

I have a .Net TCP client which connects to Telnet server (currently, for testing, via localhost):

```
tcpClient.ReceiveTimeout = 300;
tcpClient.SendTimeout = 300;
tcpClient.NoDelay = true;
LingerOption lingerOption = new LingerOption(true, 0); 
tcpClient.LingerState = lingerOption;

tcpClient.Connect(address, port);
```

After connecting to the server the client cannot detect disconnection initiated by the server (e.g. server application has closed the socket or server process has terminated).

After server is closed I can see its FIN-ACK and client's ACK in Wireshark but both client socket and TcpClient object remain in connected state.

Adding keep-alive did not help - I keep getting keep-alive response after FIN-ACK.

The only thing that allowed me to detect server disconnection immediately is periodically writing to socket which is not acceptable in my case since it pollutes the connection with garbage.

Am I missing something in socket/client configuration?

Comment: You need to keep reading. I see no code that actually reads from the socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Should I read from stream or socket?

Comment: The stream obviously, that's how you are supposed to read. You are going to need to show more code as asked. Please show what you are actually doing with this socket.

Comment: @RemyLebeau In the process of grabbing the code to post it here as suggested by Charlieface I found what was the problem: before reading from the stream I checked DataAvailable and didn't always call Read(). Now I see that one should always call Read() to get either: the data (when it's available), or IOException (when there is no data), or zero bytes (when server closed connection). Would you like to post your comment as an answer so that I could mark it as accepted?

Comment: @jackhab I've done so now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the server closes the connection gracefully (ie, sends a `FIN`), the client socket will enter a readable state, and a subsequent read on that socket will report success with 0 bytes received. This is the typical way to detect socket closure.